# MPI MergeSort Signal: Abort trap: 6 (6)

Tags: arrays, c, parallel-processing, mpi, mergesort

I am new to MPI. My sequential version of the code is the same of this, except for the MPI functions and the part about the rank. I was trying to implement a parallel version of merge sorting. My parallel implementation is the following:

```
//MPI MERGE SORT
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<mpi.h>

void merge(int arr[], int indexA, int indexB, int end, int arrOut[]);
void mergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[]);

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int rank, n_ranks;
    int size;
    int *sub_array, *temp;
    int N = 10;
    int my_array[N];
    int outputArray[N];
    int length = sizeof(my_array) / sizeof(my_array[0]);
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        my_array[i]=rand()%100 + 1;
    }
    //print the array 
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf("%d ", my_array[i]);
    }   

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n_ranks);

    size=N/n_ranks;
    sub_array=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    temp=malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    MPI_Scatter(my_array, size, MPI_INT, sub_array, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    mergeSort(sub_array, 0, length-1, temp);
    MPI_Gather(sub_array, size, MPI_INT, outputArray, size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    if(rank==0){
        int *temp_array=malloc(N*sizeof(int));
        mergeSort(outputArray, 0, length-1, temp_array);
        for(i=0; i<N; i++){
            printf("%d ", temp_array[i]);
        }
        free(temp_array);
    }

    free(my_array);
    free(sub_array);
    free(temp);

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    
} 


void merge(int arr[], int indexA, int indexB, int end, int arrOut[]){
    int i=indexA, j=indexB, k=indexA;
    while(i<=indexB-1 && j<=end){
        if(arr[i]<arr[j]){
            //i=i+1;
            arrOut[k]=arr[i++];
        }
        else{
            //j=j+1;
            arrOut[k]=arr[j++];
        }
        k++;
    }
    while(i<=indexB-1){
        //i++;
        arrOut[k]=arr[i++];
        k++;
    }
    while(j<=end){
        //j++;
        arrOut[k]=arr[j++];
        k++;
    }
    for(i=indexA; i<=end; i++)
        arr[i]=arrOut[i];
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int inf, int sup, int arrOut[]){
    int medium;
    if(inf<sup){
        medium=(inf+sup)/2;
        mergeSort(arr, inf, medium, arrOut);
        mergeSort(arr, medium+1, sup, arrOut);
        merge(arr, inf, medium+1, sup, arrOut);
    }
}
```

It seems working, in the sense that the array is sorted, but I have these errors after the printing of the array:

```
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] Signal: Abort trap: 6 (6)
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] Signal code:  (0)
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff2036ad7d _sigtramp + 29
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x000000000000400a 0x0 + 16394
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] [ 2] 0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff20279720 abort + 120
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] [ 3] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007fff2015a430 has_default_zone0 + 0
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] [ 4] 0   libsystem_malloc.dylib              0x00007fff2015d4c8 malloc_report + 151
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] [ 5] 0   a.out                               0x000000010be0fc1f main + 831
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] [ 6] 0   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20341631 start + 1
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] [ 7] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
[Brunos-MBP-4:03022] *** End of error message ***
```

Comment: This is typically caused by a previous memory corruption. at first glance, `mergeSort(my_array, 0, length-1, temp);` is the offending line.

Comment: `int my_array[N]; ... free(my_array);` You cannot free an array on the stack. You are only allowed to pass an address to `free` that you have received from `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I comment the `free(my_array)` line there is no error. So, I can guess that now is ok the program, right?

Comment: It gives the correct result but the useful merge is only performed on rank zero.

Comment: Yes, what do you suggest in order to improve?

Comment: start describing your parallel algorithm in plain English and let's compare it with your code!

Answer (score 1):

Your design does not make sense. You scatter `my_array` into `sub_array`, but then everyone sorts `my_array`. And then you gather `sub_array`, which hasn't changed, into `output_array`, so the gather/scatter basically does a copy from `my_array` into `output_array`. And then you sort the whole array on rank zero.

1. You probably meant to sort `sub_array`?
2. Sorting the gathered array on process zero takes exactly as long with or without the sorted sub array.

So your parallelism does not gain you anything. Sorting the subarray is a good first step, but then instead of a gather, do a recursive merge.

Comment: Yes, sorry, in the mergeSort between Scatter and Gather there was a typo: I fixed, now it merges sub_array

Comment: I have not understood the second point of your answer. You mean that I have to remove the MPI_Gather?

Comment: Doing a gather and then sorting the whole array on process zero is pointless. You might as well sort it on process zero to begin with. Sorting the subarrays is good, but then you need to merge them recursively: first between process 0-1 and 2-3 and 4-5 et cetera, then 0-2 4-6 et cetera, then 0-4 8-12 et cetera et cetera.